# Duplicating all SQL rows and simultaneously changing the data

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to duplicate every row in my table, but in the duplicate row the value of one column will need to overwrite an existing value in another column (an intermediary step in normalising my tables).

So what I need is something like

```
INSERT INTO `performers` SELECT * FROM `performers` 
SET `performers`.`piano` = `performers`.`singing`
```

As I'm no good at SQL the above, as expected, didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You want all columns to be inserted but 1 column in the duplicated row should have value of another column. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Juniad correct - Have edited teh question to make this clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only the duplicate row needs to have this values changed, then you can modify your `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO `performers`(col1, col2, col3, piano, singing)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, singing, singing
FROM `performers`
```

Comment: Is there no way around specifying all the column names?

Comment: @wheresrhys there is a way if the number of items in your select match the number of fields in the database :)

Comment: Yeah, there is. You can `INSERT` first and then recognize de duplicated value (hard to do) and then `UPDATE` those records. So, you can do it, but it makes no sense. And you **should** always specify all the columns instead of using `*`

Answer (score 0):

From your question I think you want to duplicate the row and then copy content of `singing` column into `piano` column?

```
INSERT INTO performers (row1, row2, row3, piano)
SELECT row1, row2, row3, singing
FROM performers
```